# Error: [$compile:tpload] in iOS

Tags: javascript, android, ios, angularjs, ngroute

I have developed an application in AngularJS. My application have 2 controllers and 5 templates. This application works absolutely fine on Android and Windows platform. But, whenever I try to access this application on iOS it gives me following error

> Error: [$compile:tpload]

I have tried to switch to the template that's working fine and render on load. But, the error is still the same.

I am suspecting some issue with my app.js but not really definite.

```
var App = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute', 'ngCookies','ngDialog'])
        .config(config)
        .run(run);
config.$inject = ['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider'];

function config($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/home', {
            controller: 'FirstController',
            templateUrl: 'templates/FirstPage.html',
            controllerAs: 'ctrl'
        })
        .when('/home1', {
            controller: 'FirstController',
            templateUrl: 'templates/SecondPage.html',
            controllerAs: 'ctrl'
        })
        .when('/home2', {
            controller: 'FirstController',
            templateUrl: 'templates/thirdPage.html',
            controllerAs: 'ctrl'
        })
        .when('/loginRedirect', {
            controller: 'LoginController',
            templateUrl: 'templates/LoginRedirect.html',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })
        .when('/login', {
            controller: 'LoginController',
            templateUrl: 'templates/Login.html',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/login' });
} 

run.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$location', '$cookies', '$http','ngDialog'];

function run($rootScope, $location, $cookies, $http,ngDialog) {
    // keep user logged in after page refresh
    $rootScope.globals = $cookies.getObject('globals') || {};
    if ($rootScope.globals.currentUser) {
        $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + $rootScope.globals.currentUser.authdata;
    }

    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {

        var restrictedPage = ['/login'].indexOf($location.path()) === -1;
        var loggedIn = $rootScope.globals.currentUser;
        if (!restrictedPage && !loggedIn) {
            $location.path('/login');
        }
    });
}
```

When I execute my application my login page display perfectly fine. On login it redirects me to loginRedirect page. But, when I try to access any page after that i.e. FirstPage, SecondPage or thirdPage it throws me following exception.

But, remember these problems only happen when I access my application on any iOS machine. i.e. iPhone (Safari or Chrome), iPad (Safari or Chrome).

I hope anyone had same issue or probably have the solution for this problem.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. @Wasif Kirmani - Did you find any solution?